# VPN connects from home but not from work or mobile data

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN configured on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I am able to use this VPN service from one network but not from others and would appreciate any help.

**Home Network**
Everything works fine. I am able to connect to the VPN and browse webpages from different devices (macbook and android phone).

**Work Network**
VPN client connects but I am unable to browse webpages on any device.
Pinging hostname works so it may not be a DNS issue.
Browser pages get stuck on connecting till they timeout.
Slack client does not connect however the Dropbox client does report being connected.

**Mobile Data**
Same as work network.

**Server Config**

```
port 443
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

**Client Config**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote x.x.x.x 443  #My Server's IPAddress
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

Although this config uses port 443 I had the same problem while using the default port 1194.
I have also experimented by changing the DNS push configuration and using Google DNS servers but this does not make any difference.

Hoping someone can help.

Comment: Do you know if a corporate firewall exists at work that could be blocking requests? Does this happen on other networks than at work?

Comment: From the fact that you are using `block-outside-dns` I guess that your client is on Windows. You might try to remove that directive. I remark that ping may work in spite of DNS problems, because ping on Windows uses the DNS Client service while the browser opens a connection on the DNS port and issues a DNS query. You could try and stop this service and see whether this makes a difference. nslookup is a better test for DNS than ping because it doesn't use the service.

Comment: I would check the routes: try to do a traceroute and see whether the packets are forwarded through the VPN.

Comment: @harrymc The device I am using is a Macbook running OS X. (although I have tried from a windows 10 laptop and encounter the same issue). I have tried removing `block-outside-dns` from the client config and I still face the same issue. I am unsure if there is a firewall, however the fact that I am able to ping after being connected to the VPN should indicate that there is no firewall.

Comment: @simlev traceroute and ping both work through the vpn. Its just the browsers (firefox, chrome) and some apps (slack) that don't connect.

Comment: Have you tried other networks than at work and at home?

Comment: This is a silly question but is your work network what your trying to VPN into? This was an issue with some Aruba based VPN networks where they were unable to connect to the network when they were on the network they were trying to connect to.

Comment: @harrymc I have similar issues to what I face on my work network whilst using mobile data on my android device. The same device with no vpn settings changed works fine at home.

Comment: @JukEboX This is a personal VPN server (ubuntu 16.04 + openvpn) hosted on the cloud.

Comment: If I understand right, your PC and android have problems at work and only at work. I assume that the problem with android is in using company wifi. This issue should rightly be raised with the network admin(s) at work and the firewall rules that he/they have defined (probably in company router(s), but internal firewalls are also a possibility).

Comment: Try `lynx`/`wget`/`curl` and see if they work or give any useful error messages.

Comment: Are you using the same PC in both home and work networks ?
If not. Are you using the same OS? Win 10? Any split-tunneling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest trying port 443 with TCP protocol. Since this is the HTTPS port most firewalls don't probe the packets over TCP 443 as they are expected to be encrypted. So this makes VPN data packets to have better chance to survive through the firewall:

```
proto udp
port 1194
```

My second suggestion, having a HTTP proxy such as Squid running on the same server with the OpenVPN and configure it to listen on port 443. Make sure secure that server. With proxy, you can make your Openvpn server listening on the local IP and default port as only proxy service running on the localhost will actually connect to it. No need to change the default server config :

```
# SERVER
proto udp
port 1194

# You can easily change the client. On the client, you can configure it to 
# connect to the VPN over proxy by adding changing a couple of lines :

# CLIENT
proto udp
http-proxy <SERVER IP> 443
remote <SERVER IP> 1194
```

Last, if none of the above work, you may try [finding a better MTU](https://www.sonassi.com/help/magestack/setting-correct-mtu-for-openvpn).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your server logs to confirm the connection is really completing?

Also, is that your full client conf?

If so, I am not sure how this is working at all, considering the server has `tls-auth ta.key 0` - you would need this configured on both ends (with the client end using a 1 instead of 0) to be able to actually connect.

I would start by validating your premises, and as other have suggested, then start obsessing about routing tables and firewalls at work.